# How can I block Android apps to send emails on my behalf?

Tags: applications, email, gmail, spam

In some Android apps there is a "Login with GMail" option. I often login with that.

Some apps are sending emails on my behalf to my GMail contacts, as I saw them in my "Sent items". I want to know how can I stop those apps spamming my friends? This is very irritating.

To stop the spamming I logged out from my device but still there are sent mails. If I uninstall the app there is no more sent mails, but I don't think this is the best solution available. Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to go into your Google Account settings and revoke issued permissions for any app which you no longer wish to have access to your Google account.

You can review connected apps at https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en